# Getting error when Calculating the Sum of premium values using DAX on a slowly changing dimension

Tags: ssas, dax, ssas-tabular

Using DAX - I need to calculate the total premium amount for policies with a certain status - using a slowly changing dimension as a source.

This is something that's running within SSAS tabular model.

The solution has two tables - dim_date (which is a calendar table) and a Dim_contract (which have all my policies listed)
The Dim_Contract table is a slowly changing dimension.

The table format:

```
DW_ContractID   DW_EffectiveFromDate    contract_number actual_recurring_collection ContractStatusTLA
-2145825896 22 August    2018   4303140 80  PIN
-2145627139 26 September 2018   4303140 80  INF
-2145428382 09 October   2018   4303140 80  Can
-2145229625 21 August    2018   4303142 100 PIN
-2145030868 22 September 2018   4303142 100 NTU
-2144832111 02 September 2018   4303999 50  PIN
-2144633354 03 September 2018   4303999 50  INF
```

I've done a calculation to count the policies - which work 100%.
With this calc, we count the number of policies for each time period. (depending what the user selects)

Example - if we want to count the number of policies as at the end of September per status we should get:

```
INF: 2 (This is counting policy numbers 4303140 and 4303999 as their last status is INF)
CAN: 0 
NTU: 1
```

The code used to do the counts:

```
PolicyCount_NTU :=
IF (
    MIN ( DIM_Date[Date] )
        >= CALCULATE ( MIN ( DIM_Contract[DW_EffectiveFromDate] ), ALL ( DIM_Contract ) ),
    IF (
        MIN ( DIM_Date[Date] )
            <= CALCULATE ( MAX ( DIM_Contract[DW_EffectiveFromDate] ), ALL ( DIM_Contract ) ),
        CALCULATE (
            COUNTROWS (
                FILTER (
                    DIM_Contract,
                    DIM_Contract[DW_ContractID]
                        = CALCULATE (
                            MAX ( DIM_Contract[DW_ContractID] ),
                            ALL ( DIM_Contract ),
                            DIM_Contract[contract_number] = EARLIER ( DIM_Contract[contract_number] ),
                            ( DIM_Contract[DW_EffectiveFromDate] ) <= VALUES ( DIM_Date[Date] )
                        )
                )
            ),
            LASTDATE ( DIM_Date[Date] ),
            DIM_Contract[ContractStatusTLA] = "NTU"
        )
    )
)
```

The problem comes in with the calc to get the sum of the amounts...
I used this code:

```
PolicyAPI_NTU :=
IF (
    MIN ( DIM_Date[Date] )
        >= CALCULATE ( MIN ( DIM_Contract[DW_EffectiveFromDate] ), ALL ( DIM_Contract ) ),
    IF (
        MIN ( DIM_Date[Date] )
            <= CALCULATE ( MAX ( DIM_Contract[DW_EffectiveFromDate] ), ALL ( DIM_Contract ) ),
        CALCULATE (
            SUM ( DIM_Contract[actual_recurring_collection] ),
            (
                FILTER (
                    DIM_Contract,
                    DIM_Contract[DW_ContractID]
                        = CALCULATE (
                            MAX ( DIM_Contract[DW_ContractID] ),
                            ALL ( DIM_Contract ),
                            DIM_Contract[contract_number] = EARLIER ( DIM_Contract[contract_number] ),
                            DIM_Contract[DW_EffectiveFromDate] < VALUES ( DIM_Date[Date] )
                        )
                )
            ),
            LASTDATE ( DIM_Date[Date] ),
            DIM_Contract[ContractStatusTLA] = "NTU"
        )
    )
)
```

Using the last piece of code to get the SUM of the amounts doesn't work - I get an error: Error: Calculation error in measure 'DIM_Contract'[PolicyAPI_NTU]: A table of multiple values was supplied where a single value was expected.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your problem is here

```
DIM_Contract[DW_EffectiveFromDate] < VALUES ( DIM_Date[Date] )
```

The DAX doesn't know how to do a comparison if `DIM_Date[Date]` has multiple values.

Try using a `MAX` or `MIN` or `LASTDATE` or something similar instead of `VALUES`.

Comment: Thanks. When I remove that line the query works (not correctly, but it brings back results). The weird part is, is that the same query works when I use CountRows. But not with Sum? As soon as I use Max or last date, I get a error that It can't be used as part of a boolean check...

Comment: Yeah, you can't use a max in a basic `CALCULATE` filter. You'd need to put in inside a `FILTER` function: `FILTER(DIM_Contract, DIM_Contract[DW_EffectiveFromDate] < MAX ( DIM_Date[Date] )`.